# Remove rows containing keyword and indented records below it

Tags: excel, vba

Attached is a small sample of my data, row 7, 8, 12 and 13 are parent headings and rows 9-11 are child headings of row 8 because it is indented under it. When I run Range().IndentLevel, it returns 2 for rows 7, 8, 12, 13 and 3 for rows 9-11. These are the only two IndentLevels in the column

[image]

I am trying to remove all the rows with the keyword "Pursuit Adjustment" which I was able to do with the following:

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    
    strSearch = "Pursuit Adjustment"
    
    Set ws = Sheets("PFSR All (formatted)")
    
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and delete visible rows
        With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
          .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
          .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
```

However I am having difficulties figuring out two things:

1. How do I also remove all child headings of the associated parent heading in my `strSearch` (rows 9-11)?
2. In my  `strSearch`, I have only specified "Pursuit Adjustment", how can I add multiple search conditions to it?

Comment: Please, better clarify what 'indentation' does mean in an Excel cell. Are there a specific number of spaces?

Comment: When I run Range().IndentLevel, it returns 2 for rows 7, 8, 12, 13 and 3 for rows 9-11.

Comment: Please edit your question with the new information, as in the q you are saying that 7, 8, 12, 13 are not indented. Is there any lines (e.g. above line 7) with `IndentLevel` 1 or 0? Can there be other `Indentlevel`s anywhere in the column?

Comment: Then, I am afraid that it cannot be done without iteration

Comment: I have edited my questions, only IndentLevels 2 and 3 exist in the column

Comment: And the one to be removed should the ones with `IndentLevel = 2`?

Comment: I want to remove all rows with "Pursuit Adjustment" which is IndentLevel 2 and as well as the IndentLevel 3 rows directly below it, in this case I want to remove rows 8-11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lRow As Long
Dim strSearch As Variant

strSearch = Array("Pursuit Adjustment", "str2", "str3") 'Put here all the strings you want to search and delete
    
Set ws = Sheets("PFSR All (formatted)")

With ws
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    
    For i = LBound(strSearch) To UBound(strSearch)
        For j = 1 To lRow
            If InStr(.Range("A" & j), strSearch(i)) Then
                .Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
                Do While .Range("A" & j).IndentLevel > 2
                    .Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
                Loop
                j = j - 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code, too. It will be faster, placing the necessary ranges in a `Union` range and delete them at once, at the end. The actual code only selects the rows to be deleted. If it returns what you need, you can replace `Select` with `Delete` on the last code line:

```
Sub teleteSpecificRowsAndIndentedBelow()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, strSearch As String, lRow As Long, arrA, arrSearch, El
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, rngDel As Range, boolFound As Boolean
    
    arrSearch = Split("Pursuit Adjustment,second string,third string,etc", ",") 'no space after comma!!!
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' Sheets("PFSR All (formatted)")
        lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        arrA = ws.Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value 'put it in an array to make iteration faster
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrA)
            For Each El In arrSearch
                If InStr(arrA(i, 1), El) > 0 Then boolFound = True: Exit For
            Next
            If boolFound Then
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = ws.Range("A" & i)
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, ws.Range("A" & i))
                End If
                'start searching for indented following rows:
                For j = 1 To lRow
                    If ws.Range("A" & i + j).IndentLevel < 2 Then Exit For
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, ws.Range("A" & i + j))
                Next j
                i = i + j - 1: boolFound = False
            End If
        Next i
        If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Select 'if the output is correct, please replace Select with Delete
End Sub
```